# Set up an adhoc network in Windows Vista to connect to and share the Internet connection with Mac OS X

Tags: macos, windows-vista, ad-hoc-network

I want to create an adhoc network between Windows Vista and Mac OS X 10.6 to share internet connection of the Windows machine. A problem I have, is how to connect these two computers.

I have created ad hoc network on Windows machine and chose WEP (as suggested on some forums) as the connection encryption. However the effect is strange, Widows Vista still reported that it is not connected but Mac OS X managed to connect. Does anybody successfully set up such a configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The following article can be used as a check-list:
[How to: Create an Ad-Hoc Network, Part 2](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3822651/How-to-Create-an-Ad-Hoc-Network-Part-2.htm)

If everything checks-out, it would help to know how OS X manages to connect to Vista but Vista cannot connect, what does "connect" mean, and whether you use static or dynamic IP (for dynamic, which is the DHCP server). Please also try ping and route and include their output in the post.