# Set up ad hoc wireless connection between Windows Vista and Mac OS X

Tags: macos, windows-vista, macbook, ad-hoc-network

I have the following problem - Windows Vista does not connect to adhoc wireless network created on my Macbook. I have tried to create secured (with 40 bit key) and unsecured network but Windows Vista still has problems to connect. Windows VISTA informs me -- after 5 minutes of attempts - that setting up the connection -- with my adhoc network -- took too much time.

My question: do I need to configure some settings on Vista to connect it to my Macbook? Maybe it is a problem with DHCP?

Edited: I have tried the other way: [Set up an adhoc network in Windows Vista to connect to and share the Internet connection with Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/202890/set-up-an-adhoc-network-in-windows-vista-to-connect-to-and-share-the-internet-con)

Comment: Can you try it the other way around? Create an adhoc network on Vista and see if your macbook can connect to it. It's worth a try.

Comment: Have you tried setting up static IP addresses on both computers?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this between Mac OSX and Linux, and I just used static IP's.  That may not be as convenient, but it works quite well.

Cheers,
-C

Answer (score 0):

On ad-hoc networks, both Mac and Windows will give themselves IPv4 link-local addresses (169.254.x.x -- Microsoft calls these "APIPA" addresses), and connectivity will work fine.

However, both OSes might warn you that you didn't get an IP address lease via DHCP, so they'll say that your connectivity might be limited.

But if you just ignore that message, you should be able to connect just fine using the IPv4 link local addresses that both machines gave themselves.

If the warning bothers you, you could give each machine static IP addresses on the same subnet just to avoid the message, but I don't find it to be worth the hassle.