# Is there possibility to connect or use or receive a adhoc network connection from other computer

Tags: ad-hoc-network

> netsh wlan connect MyShared Interface=Wi-Fi

result:
"Connection request was completed successfully"

But i opened chrome browser, accessed google.com.
Failed to open the page

So how do i connect a adhoc network connection which is started by another computer in windows 8.1 pro.

Comment: Are you trying to use the other computer's Internet connection to get online?

Comment: Correct, I've 3 laptops with me. (windows7, Xp, windows 8.1 pro) started adhoc in windows 7, checked with the xp system.Yes it can connect that adhoc network.Now i checked with windows 8.1 pro, But i can't.Please help me

Comment: How do you know that the XP system is connected correctly?

Comment: I can access google.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set up an adhoc network in Windows Vista to connect to and share the Internet connection with Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/202890/set-up-an-adhoc-network-in-windows-vista-to-connect-to-and-share-the-internet-co)

Comment: Note : Adhoc network is created in windows 7 machine

Answer (score 1):

Just creating an adhoc network does not share your internet connection, for security reasons. You have to do that as a separate step. How to do that will depend on which operating system you are using.